# Como guardar un valor ingresado en un prompt en una variable mediante un loop

Tags: javascript

Como seria para guardar el valor 0 introducido en prompt en variable valor y asi en las demas?
Gracias

```js
let valor, valor1; valor2, valor3;

 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  let prompt('Introduce un valor para guardarlo en una variable');
  
  valor = i;
  valor1 = i;
  valor2 = i;
  valor3 = i;
  console.log(valor);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un array  `valor=[]`, y cuando recorras el for ir guardando los valores de `i` en `valor[]`. Después un nuevo for para mostrarlo. Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

**Código:**

```
let valor = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
   {
       valor[i] = prompt('Introduce un valor para guardarlo en una variable: ');
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
   {
       console.log(valor[i]+" ");
   }
```

Comment: Queria mas bien guardar el primer valor en una variable1 el segundo en otra y asi sucesivamente, por ejemplo crear 10 variables: variable1 variable2 de forma automatica con el loop y ahi asigfnandole el que he ingresado, se podria eso? Se que es una cosa sin sentido solo queria saber

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar  tus valores en un array  en donde pondrás los valores que se ingrese en el prompt.  Si lo que quieres es tener acceso a una variable que ya defines puedes usar la expresion [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval) que ejecutaría  dinamicamente la expresión de asignación de tu valor.Adjunto ambas soluciones en el mismo ejemplo.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="ShowPrompt()">Ingresa Numeros</button>
<script>
  var list = []; //array de valores
  let valor0, valor1, valor2; //tus valores declarados

  function ShowPrompt() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var valor = prompt("Introduce el valor " + (parseInt(i) + 1) + " para guardarlo");
      
      eval(" valor" + i + " =" + valor); // aqui asignas el valor a tu varaible de forma dinamica
      list[i] = valor; // aqui guardas el valor en el array definido
      
      console.log(valor);
    }
  }
</script>
```